# PHP don't create cookies

Tags: php, mobile, cookies

i have a problem with my php code. I want detect if mobile user, then redirect to choose.php, user will choose a option if he want mobile web or classic. If he choose classic redirect to cookie.php and it should create cookie "web" with value "ano". And index should not ask for Mobile/classic again.
But it always do.. You can try on [www.luxweb.sk](http://luxweb.sk)

Index :

```
<?php
if( preg_match("/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['web'])){
       die(header("Location: wp-content/themes/lux/choose.php")); 
    }
    elseif($_COOKIE['web'] != "ano"){
       die(header("Location: wp-content/themes/lux/choose.php"));  
    }
    else {
        //nothing
    }
}  
?>
```

Choose :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Vyberte si zobrazenie</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://m.luxweb.sk">Mobilná verzia</a>
        <a href="cookie.php">Desktopovná verzia (responsívna)</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cookie :

```
<?php
    if(setcookie('web', 'ano', time()+1000)){
       header("Location: http://luxweb.sk"); 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the 'path' part of your cookie ... just ran through a test and the cookie data set is:

```
Name       'web'
Value      'ano'
Host       'luxweb.sk'
Path       '/wp-content/themes/lux/'
Expires    'At end of session'
Secure     'No'
HttpOnly   'No'
```

(ignore the Expires bit - my browser is set to delete all cookies on shut-down so **every** cookie expires at the end of the session)

Because you're not specifying the path at the time you're setting it, the path to the directory containing the script calling `setcookie()` is used as a default - so : **/wp-content/themes/lux/**

If you want that cookie accessible from the root of your domain, you'll need to use:

```
setcookie('web', 'ano', time()+1000, '/')
```

... or better perhaps:

```
setcookie('web', 'ano', time()+1000, '/', '.luxweb.sk')
```

It will be then accessible from the root of any sub-domain of luxweb.sk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the string `$path` paremeter

The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

```
setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

see examples on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

something like:

```
setcookie('web', 'ano', time()+1000, '/');
```

If you want the cookie will be available for every page of  your website

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `<?php session_start(); ?>` to the top of your script

[PHP: session_start - Manual](https://www.php.net/session_start)

Comment: Why? I see no session here?

Comment: My mistake... I thought he was setting session variables (which would arguably be a neater way to do this).

Comment: Doesn't work.. Another solution ? Is it possible, that my hosting has blocked cookies ?